# How can I solve Uncaught TypeError: pendingLegacyContextWarning.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

react-dom.development.js:11571 Uncaught TypeError: pendingLegacyContextWarning.forEach is not a function
at Object.ReactStrictModeWarnings.flushLegacyContextWarning (react-dom.development.js:11571:1)
at flushRenderPhaseStrictModeWarningsInDEV (react-dom.development.js:23819:1)
at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:23005:1)
at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)
at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276:1)
at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:22990:1)
at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22329:1)
at react-dom.development.js:11327:1
at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)
at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276:1)

An React error occurred when I added a script to index.html. how can i solve it?

Comment: Why add script to index.html if you can add to index.js or app.js?

Comment: It works when you add a script to index.html.

Comment: Why use react then?

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. There's no code here so there's no way to help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no code here from the OP, so it's hard to help, but here's a reproduction that I came across in my code which led me to this thread:

```js
const Map = () => <p>hello world</p>;

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Map />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Output is:

```
Error {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: pendingLegacyContextWarning.forEach is not a function",
  "filename": "https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js",
  "lineno": 12963,
  "colno": 35
}
```

The problem seems to be the `Map` name. The fix is to simply change the name to something else:

```js
const Map_ = () => <p>hello world</p>;

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Map_ />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

This isn't necessarily OP's exact problem or the only cause. I don't see many other resources for this error.